# Azure cannot connect to SQL Server

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am an Azure newcomer.

I went through
[Get Started with Azure Cloud Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started) tutorial and can run the Contoso Ad app locally.

When I push it to my dev/test Azure account, the app cannot see the database.

**You can see it live here: [My Dev/Test Azure instance running Contoso Ad App](http://muniagenda.cloudapp.net/)**

I can run SSMS locally and connect to my database:

[image]
(this works fine)

I did have to add my home IP Address to the Firewall rules:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way I can see more about what Azure doesn't like when trying to connect to the database?
2. I followed the tutorial step-by-step, and I'm sure my connection Strings are correct, especially since I can connect from SSMS at home.  Any firewall changes that need to be made so an Azure Web App can see an Azure SQL Server database?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: In the tutorial you link to they write about using the release .config file - are you sure the config file is not changed when doing a release build? Looks like the connection to the DB times out and that could be caused by an invalid connection string.

Comment: @NicklasMøllerJepsen So, coming from a Java background, I didn't fully understand the `Web.Release.config` file, but when I do a local Release build, and go to `ContosoAdsWeb\bin\ContosoAdsWeb.dll.config`, I am seeing `<add name="ContosoAdsContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=ContosoAds; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: @NicklasMøllerJepsen I did find this article: https://forums.asp.net/t/1532038.aspx.  It sounds like the local Release directory can be different that what is published to Azure.  Is there a way I can see what Azure has after doing the publish?

Comment: @NicklasMøllerJepsen Thank you for your help!!!  If you promote your comment to an answer I'll upvote it since it lead me to the correct answer, which I will post.  It had to do w/me not understanding the whole Web.Debug.Config/Web.Release.Config thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be me not fully understanding how

- `Web.Config`
- `Web.Debug.Config`
- `Web.Release.Config`

interact.

I learned that `Web.Release.Config` is only modifying upon a Web/Azure Publish, so I did not see the changes reflected in the local `<project>\bin\Release` folder.

I also learned that by changing the Connection String name in `Web.Release.Config`, this caused it to not match and transform/overwrite the value in `Web.Config`.

Comment: Pretty common misunderstanding and quite a huge annoyance of the older ASP.NET configuration system. I.e. Debug config is not used if you just run it on IIS Express in Debug mode. Luckily things are much better in ASP.NET Core where the configuration files are always used according to environment.

Comment: @juunas Thanks. Adding to my frustrations was that I haven't done .NET Web development for several years ... I think ASP.NET MVC was new at that time and Web Forms was the dominant framework.  It looks like a lot has changed since then.